# Zend Framework application times out with strange message

Tags: apache, zend-framework, timeout, php

I was hoping someone could help me figure out why my application keeps timing out.
It is built using Zend Framework.
I'm trying to run a script that takes a few minutes to finish.
It works fine on my local machine (MAMP) but times out on the prod server (Ubuntu).
The relevant php.ini settings on both servers are: 
max_execution_time = 600
max_input_time = 600
memory_limit = 512M
post_max_size = 8M

It should run for 10 minutes before timing out right?
On the Ubuntu server it'll only run for 1-2 minutes and then time out with this message printed in the middle of the browser:

"Backend server did not respond in time.
App server is too busy and cannot handle requests in time."

Pretty sure it's a Zend message but I can't find anything about it on the internet.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Does not seems to be zend message, matchable and reasonable matches on google is this : http://code.google.com/p/scalr/source/browse/scalarizr/tags/0.6.6/share/nginx/html/502.html?r=300

Comment: Agreed with the above. This is not a Zend Framework error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was nginx running on the load balancer.
The error was coming from nginx which is running under scalr. Hence the *"Backend server did not respond in time. App server is too busy and cannot handle requests in time."* - a scalr error.
Once the proxy_read_timeout setting was raised in the nginx config the script stopped timing out.

Thanks for the scalr link above - pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

That message looks like it's from mod_fastcgi.

When you run PHP under FastCGI (or you run anything under FastCGI), the PHP script is a separate entity from the web server.  You've configured your PHP process to run for up to 10 minutes, but Apache/mod_fastcgi is configured to only wait some shorter period for your PHP script to start returning data.

The idea is to insulate the apache process from external processes that go off into the weeds never to return (eventually, apache would run out of listeners)

If you have access to the FastCGI configuration section of httpd.conf, check out the values for -appConnTimeout or -idle-timeout.

Unfortunately (or fortunately, if you're a sysadmin at some hosting company), you can't override these settings via .htaccess or even per virtualhost.  At least, not according to the [documentation](http://www.fastcgi.com/mod_fastcgi/docs/mod_fastcgi.html#FastCgiServer)

Comment: Thanks for the response. mod_fastcgi is not installed on the server though. Pretty sure it's coming from scalr. I've got the sysadmin looking into it.

Comment: If not fastcgi, then what?  How is apache talking to PHP?  Given that error message, I'd be very surprised to hear you're running vanilla mod_php

Comment: nginx running through scalr on the load balancer. Forgot to think of the load balancer.